# How to add controls to stringbuilder?

Tags: html, asp.net, vb.net, stringbuilder, html-select

```
Dim dropdownList As New DropDownList
dropdownList.ID = "ddlList2"  

Dim strb As New StringBuilder
strb.Append("<div id='test1' runat='server'>")
strb.Append(dropdownList)
strb.Append("</div>")
strb.Append("Title")
divid.InnerHtml=strb.ToString
```

Output

the page showing "System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList"
How to add controls to stringbuilder?

Comment: StringBuilder can only deal with strings as far as the control is not a string type, the code performs the simplest conversion to string (Type name). You have to put there the String-Type Property you want, I guess that it is the name, so you should write strb.Append(dropdownList.Name)

Comment: It looks like you're trying to write the HTML for the `DropDownList` and putting that (along with other HTML) into the `InnerHtml` of a div.  The HTML for the `DropDownList` is emitted by the control, and I don't think there's an easy way to get to it.  Perhaps if you edit your question and explain more of what you are trying to accomplish we can suggest some solutions.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add controls dynamically you need to use the << AnyControl >>.Controls.Add() method. Its recommended to do so in pre-init.

You can't add any control into StringBuilder. Also its purpose is not for rendering server side controls. For all its methods, it would internally typecast the objects to string if the object is not of type string. For more information check [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder_methods.aspx)